# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, node-modules

Soo, I have been trying to make a small login page for my webpage using the firebase Real-Time database. I have installed the firebase node module, but I keep getting the same error whenever I try to run this. The exact error message is:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

I have NO idea why this is happening; I tried all the methods like clearing cache, reinstalling firebase, using "./firebase/app", but it never worked! I even remade the project from scratch, only for the error to reappear. I know I can use CDN but I want to use node modules because they have autocomplete support for Visual Studio Code.

EDIT: So, I realized the problem, I was using firebase v9, which REQUIRES a module bundler. The issue was that I was NOT using an actual module bundler, which is a necessity for firebase v9 web apps... In other words, ***MY ISSUE HAS BEEN FIXED***